# Can't separately input date in thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I've been trying to add **dateOfBirth** fields to registration form. I want to separate the date to 3 fields: day, month and year.

When I enter the date to fields, I get in the controller current date and strange year - "3890".

my HTML code:

```html
<div class="form-group row">
    <label for="confirm" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Date of Birth</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input id="day" type="text" th:field="*{dateOfBirth.day}"/>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group row">
    <label for="confirm" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label"></label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input id="month" type="text" th:field="*{dateOfBirth.month}"/>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group row">
    <label for="confirm" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label"></label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input id="year" type="text" th:field="*{dateOfBirth.year}"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

my controllers code:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/register")
public String showRegistrationForm(WebRequest request, Model model) {
    ChannelDTO channelData = new ChannelDTO();
    model.addAttribute("channel", channelData);
    return "registration";
}

@PostMapping(value = "/register")
public ModelAndView registerUserAccount(@ModelAttribute("channel") @Valid ChannelDTO channelData, BindingResult result,
                                        HttpServletRequest request, Errors errors, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {
    Channel channel = null;
    if (!result.hasErrors()) {
        channel = createUserAccount(channelData, result);
    }

    // logic...

    return new ModelAndView("redirect:/register/select-interests");
}
```

my ChannelDTO:

```
@PasswordMatches
public class ChannelDTO {

    @NotNull
    @NotEmpty
    @Email
    private String email;

    @NotNull
    @NotEmpty
    private String name;

    //@NotNull
    //@NotEmpty
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd")
    private Date dateOfBirth;

    @NotNull
    @NotEmpty
    private String password;

    @NotNull
    @NotEmpty
    private String matchingPassword;
}
```

I would appreciate any help, thank you.

Comment: this is "old" Date problem, year is 1900 based, month 0 and day 1. Java8 java.time is much better

Comment: But there is no separeted fields for day, month & year. How can I get separeted inputs for day, month, year?

Comment: Hmmm.... java8 LocalDate is immutable, so have only getters (it is good design, but problem for You) ... integration with editable fields require kind of proxy

Comment: You mean that the only one way to split date in inputs is to create proxy object?

Comment: on the margin: do not edit question too deep, sequence of dialog is hard to understand

Comment: Thank you, I will note this for the future. I though that the picture distract attention from my main question: How can i split date for 3 inputs(day, month, year) in thymeleaf

Answer (score 0):

You're using the original Date class (it's not related to java 8's datetime API):
[java.util.Date](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#setYear(int))

The documentation states that setYear:

> Sets the year of this Date object to be the specified value plus 1900.

So you need to subtract your year value by 1900.
Probably you can do it with th:value, or in the controller you can subtract the dateOfBirth by 1900 before the logic part.

Or you can use a Thymeleaf java8 datetime API module, like this one:
[Thymeleaf - Module for Java 8 Time API compatibility](https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf-extras-java8time)

If you want to subtract your date by 1900, try this out:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/register")
public ModelAndView registerUserAccount(@ModelAttribute("channel") @Valid ChannelDTO channelData, BindingResult result, HttpServletRequest request, Errors errors, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(channelData.getDateOfBirth());
    cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, cal.get(Calendar.YEAR) - 1900);
    channelData.setDateOfBirth(cal.getTime());

    Channel channel = null;
    if (!result.hasErrors()) {
        channel = createUserAccount(channelData, result);
    }

    //logic...

    return new ModelAndView("redirect:/register/select-interests");
}
```

Also modify this line:

```
<input id="day" type="text" th:field="*{dateOfBirth.day}"/>
```

To this:

```
<input id="day" type="text" th:field="*{dateOfBirth.date}"/>
```

You can also try to use not Date type for dateOfBirth, but Calendar.

### EDIT

There are 2 options that you can try:

**Option 1:**

Leave ChannelDTO as is and modify your controller like so:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/register")
public ModelAndView registerUserAccount(@ModelAttribute("channel") @Valid ChannelDTO channelData,
                                        BindingResult result, HttpServletRequest request, Errors errors, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(channelData.getDateOfBirth());
    cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, cal.get(Calendar.YEAR) - 1900);
    cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) - 1);
    channelData.setDateOfBirth(cal.getTime());

    Channel channel = null;
    if (!result.hasErrors()) {
        channel = createUserAccount(channelData, result);
    }

    //logic...

    return new ModelAndView("redirect:/register/select-interests");
}
```

Modify your html to this:

```
<div class="form-group row">
    <label for="confirm" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Date of Birth</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input id="day" type="text" th:field="*{dateOfBirth.date}" />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group row">
    <label for="confirm" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label"></label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input id="month" type="text" th:field="*{dateOfBirth.month}" />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group row">
    <label for="confirm" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label"></label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input id="year" type="text" th:field="*{dateOfBirth.year}" />
    </div>
</div>
```

**Option 2:**

Create a new class, which will be used to hold the year, month and day values:

```
public class CustomDate {
    public CustomDate() {
    }

    private int year;
    private int month;
    private int day;

    public int getYear() {
        return year;
    }
    public void setYear(int year) {
        this.year = year;
    }
    public int getMonth() {
        return month;
    }
    public void setMonth(int month) {
        this.month = month -1;
    }
    public int getDay() {
        return day;
    }
    public void setDay(int day) {
        this.day = day;
    }
}
```

Modify ChannelDTO class like so:

```
public class ChannelDTO {

    public ChannelDTO() {
    }

    @NotNull
    @NotEmpty
    @Email
    private String email;

    @NotNull
    @NotEmpty
    private String name;

    //@NotNull
    //@NotEmpty
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd")
    private Date dateOfBirth;

    private CustomDate customDateOfBirth;

    @NotNull
    @NotEmpty
    private String password;

    @NotNull
    @NotEmpty
    private String matchingPassword;

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Date getDateOfBirth() {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.set(customDateOfBirth.getYear(), customDateOfBirth.getMonth(), customDateOfBirth.getDay());
        return cal.getTime();
    }

    public void setDateOfBirth(Date dateOfBirth) {
        this.dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getMatchingPassword() {
        return matchingPassword;
    }

    public void setMatchingPassword(String matchingPassword) {
        this.matchingPassword = matchingPassword;
    }

    @Transient
    public CustomDate getCustomDateOfBirth() {
        return customDateOfBirth;
    }

    public void setCustomDateOfBirth(CustomDate customDateOfBirth) {
        this.customDateOfBirth = customDateOfBirth;
    }

}
```

Please note that there is a new field called customDateOfBirth, and the getter method of customDateOfBirth has a @Transient annotation which prevents JPA to insert it into the database. If you want to skip it from being serialized via Jackson, put a @JsonIgnore annotation on the getter method, too.

The getDateOfBirth method has a custom logic in it, which transforms the customDateOfBirth into Date type.

Modify your html like this:

```
<div class="form-group row">
    <label for="confirm" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Date of
        Birth</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input id="day" type="text" th:field="*{customDateOfBirth.day}" />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group row">
    <label for="confirm" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label"></label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input id="month" type="text" th:field="*{customDateOfBirth.month}" />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group row">
    <label for="confirm" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label"></label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input id="year" type="text" th:field="*{customDateOfBirth.year}" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Please note that customDateOfBirth is used in the html template.

Comment: I've tried to use this module - [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46133340/how-to-use-thymeleaf-extras-java8time-in-input). I can create nly the full date, not separated with this - ${#temporals.create(year,month,day)}. How can I create splitted date from input?

Comment: I want to avoid creating three fields (day, month, year) instead of one date in my ChannelDTO object. Could you give me an example of using Thymeleaf java8 datetime API module, please?

Comment: I think if you're using thymeleaf-java8time, you need to use LocalDate (or java.time.Temporal) type for your dateOfBirth variable in your ChannelDTO class. Other than that the thymeleaf expression you're using seems to be correct for me.

Comment: I know, I've changed it to LocalDate. But how I can built this object from 3 diferent inputs(day, month, year) in thymeleaf?

Comment: LocalDate do not have fields like day, month, year. I can not use the same expresions that i use with Date.

Comment: Can you please give me example how i can use thymeleaf-extras-java8time in input with splited date?

Comment: Your're right. So in this case maybe you should just change the date in your controller (subtract it with 1900).

Comment: Yes, it's possible. But I still get the current day and month from fields instead of entered day and month.

Comment: I can't change **th:field** value to ***{dateOfBirth.date}**, because this will give me the full date, not only the day.